# Copy data excel in format table word split list in different pages

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-word, vba

Hello and thanks in advance for your help.

1- I have a spreadsheet that Sheet1 and Sheet2 have data list of names and ID that change in daily basis in Excel, is it possible a VBA code run copy from excel to word.
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLQj9.png)                                       [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sdMO.png)

2. Sheet1 Column A, B need to copy to word format table in the exact column and row, split  in different pages, see column F show page in word.
3. Excel file sheet1 = data in column A, B rows until end.. Copy to file Test1 word template in column A, B
4. Excel file sheet2 = data in column A, B, C, rows until end, copy to file Test2  word template in column A, B, C
   [Word template1 for sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UoN4.png)                        [Word template2 for sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdvNf.png)
5. The way how paste in the word template need to be the data in different pages.
   Please help me figure out how I can get the text  from excel into the correct lines in word
   template.

Comment: [Mail Merge][1] is the functionality designed for this purpose. I recommend you take a few moments to test and learn how to do that. It will save you trouble in the long run. Alternatively, you could separate the data for the different tables on to different sheets using PowerQuery, then embed the Excel tables in the word file and reformat them. If you use VBA, you will spend a lot of time later debugging / updating it.


  [1]: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input @FlexYourData, I'm working in all your suggestion. Cheers!!